# one of kafka broker has crashed, how recover?

Tags: apache-kafka

I think I'm mixed and unclear for how kafka cluster works.

## Current structure:

I made kafka broker cluster with 3 machines by downloading from [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.6.0/kafka_2.13-2.6.0.tgz)

And one of topics are like this

```
ubuntu@kafka1:~/.kafka$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:11111 --topic multi_partitions
Topic:multi_partitions      PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:retention.ms=-1,retention.bytes=-1
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 2,1,0 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,2,1 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,0,2 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 6    Leader: 1       Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 7    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 8    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,0
        Topic: multi_partitions     Partition: 9    Leader: 1       Replicas: 2,1,0 Isr: 1,0
```

As you can see, three replicas exist but replica2 has  crashed so it doesn't work anymore.

## Questions

1. If I can recover replica2, does it sync while the data which are created during it has  crashed?
2. If I can't recover replica2, how I can add a new broker to this topic and make it copy all the data in the replica cluster?

Comment: What is your `replication factor`, `min.insync.replicas`, and `acks`?

Comment: @Steephen Thank you. `replication factor=3`, and `min.insync.replicas` doesn't matter because I use `acks=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can recover replica2, does it sync while the data which are created during it has been crashed?

As you mentioned in comment, in your cluster, `replication factor = 2` and `acks = 1`. Assume your crashed node is node2.

There are two scenarios:

**Scenario-1**: There was no topic partition elected your node2 as the leader. You are all set, you will not have data loss. Once that node comes back, topic partition leaders push the missing data to node2.

**scenario-2**: Assume there was a topic partition elected the crashed node as its leader. If that is the case cluster will select one of the other node as leader of the topic partition. When node2 comes back, and every other nodes are working fine, the new leader push the data to node2 to maintain the configuration `replication factor = 3`.

> If I can't recover replica2, how I can add a new broker to this topic
> and make it copy all the data in the replica cluster?

Cluster is capable to recover the replicas, as soon as crashed node joins the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) I understood~